# Overview of available images per image collection?

Tags: google-earth-engine, function, code-review

I´m trying to make an overview in a table or graph of the available images in Landsat, Sentinel and Modis series for a certain area of interest. Although I could solve it as follows, this is obviously very inefficient.

Does anyone have an advice how to write this more efficiently?

```
// ------INPUT------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// define a year of classification
var year_start = 1970;
var year_end = 2018;
var date_start = ee.Date.fromYMD(year_start,1,1);
var date_end = ee.Date.fromYMD(year_end,12,31);
var cloud_cover_100 = 100;
var cloud_cover_90 = 90;
var cloud_cover_80 = 80;
var cloud_cover_70 = 70;
var cloud_cover_60 = 60;
var cloud_cover_50 = 50;
var cloud_cover_40 = 40;
var cloud_cover_30 = 30;
var cloud_cover_20 = 20;
var cloud_cover_10 = 10;
var cloud_cover_5 = 5;
//     ------LANDSAT------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
var size_l8 = l8.filterBounds(aoi).filterDate(date_start,date_end).toList(1000000).length();
print('Total number of images in l8 in current time frame: ', size_l8);

l8 = l8.filterBounds(aoi).filterDate(date_start,date_end).filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUD_COVER_LAND',cloud_cover_100));
var size = l8;
print(size);
l8 = l8.filterBounds(aoi).filterDate(date_start,date_end).filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUD_COVER_LAND',cloud_cover_90));
var size = l8;
print(size);
l8 = l8.filterBounds(aoi).filterDate(date_start,date_end).filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUD_COVER_LAND',cloud_cover_80));
var size = l8;
print(size);
etc...
```

Comment: Is the code running slow or what do you mean by making it more efficient?

Comment: In the end the goal would be to make an overview of the cloud cover over time with 3 variables: 1. the amount of cloud cover, 2. the start and end date, 3. the selected satellites. Therefore I was planning to write out all these options manually, but it would take a whole lot of time and most of all is not very convenient. I was thinking if something like a function could solve this, but I´m not sure how to set it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a function to create a histogram of an image metadata (i.e. CLOUD_COVER_LAND) values, and run the function for each combination of year and image collection.

```js
var get_cloudcover_histogram = function(collection, start, end) {
  var images_in_period = collection.filterBounds(aoi)
                                  .filterDate(start, end);
  var cloudcover_histogram = images_in_period
                             .reduceColumns({
                               reducer:ee.Reducer.fixedHistogram(0,110,11),
                               selectors:['CLOUD_COVER_LAND']
                             });
  return cloudcover_histogram;
};

// Define a sample Area-of-Interest.
var aoi = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[-106.82, 36.56],
          [-106.89, 36.43],
          [-106.54, 36.43]]]);

// Define a set of years.
var years = [];
for (var i = 1970; i <= 2018; i++) {
   years.push(i);
}

// Define a set of image collections.
var collections = [
  'LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR',
  'LANDSAT/LE07/C01/T1_SR',
  'LANDSAT/LT05/C01/T1_SR'
];

for (var i_collection = 0; i_collection < collections.length; i_collection++) { 
  var collection_name = collections[i_collection];
  var collection = ee.ImageCollection(collection_name);
  for (var i_year = 0; i_year < years.length; i_year++) { 
    var year = years[i_year];
    var start = ee.Date.fromYMD(year, 1, 1);
    var end = start.advance(1, 'year');
    print(collection_name, year, get_cloudcover_histogram (collection, start, end).get('histogram'));
  }
}
```

Note that the metadata 'CLOUD_COVER_LAND' may not be set for all Landsat images.